# Adding an object to an array of favorite objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a site which lists many events and I want users who are logged in to be able to add an event to a personal list of favorite/watched events.

I have

**event.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles
```

and

**profile.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :events
```

If a user is logged in, I want to a button on each event view that adds that event to the current_user's profile. Basically, this functionality:

current_user.profile.events << event

It works to do that in the console but I can't figure out how to create a form which does this. From this looking at various answers on this website, this is what I have:

**Routes.rb**

```
map.resources :events, :member => { :create_calendar => :post }
```

**_event.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for( current_user.profile.events(event) ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Add to Calendar" %>
<% end %>
```

**events_controller.rb**

```
def create_calendar
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  current_user.profile.events << @event
end
```

Any guidance, advice, or tips would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a fan of has_and_belongs_to_many so my advice would be to ditch it and make a new model. Maybe something like this

```
class SavedEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Then you can do something like this:

Events View:

```
form_for SavedEvent.new, :url => "/events/save_event" do |f|
  f.hidden_field :event_id, :value => @event.id
  f.submit "Save Event"
end
```

Then to save it:

```
def save_event
  @saved_event = SavedEvent.new(params[:saved_event]
  @saved_event.user = current_user
  @saved_event.save
end
```

Naturally you can trim this down a bit and make it a bit more RESTful, but that would be the main building block of how I'd go about doing it.

Comment: Agreed. Making another model is easy and will be much easier to understand than overloading the meaning of profile.